# Method that return related entities using OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, asp.net-web-api

There is method `GetFull` that should use OData return related entities.

When I call `GetFull(12, "entity1,entity2")` then I will get to current object with id = 12 and related entity1 and entity2 (`http://.../api/City/12?$expand=Region`)

When I call `GetFull(12, "0")` then I want to automatical find and get all related entities from current object (`http://.../api/City/12?$expand=Region,Country`). For that I'm using reflections.

How can I improve this method? 
It's working but I'm sure that I implemented it not properly.

P.S : It was done  for user-friendly link
before:`http://.../api/City/12?$expand=Region,Country` 
now:`http://.../api/City/12/GetFull` or `http://.../api/City/12/GetFull/Region`

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetFull(int id, string entities)
{            
    string propertyList = string.Empty;

    if (!entities.Equals("0"))
    {
        propertyList = entities;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
            {
                propertyList += prop.Name + ",";
            }
        }

        propertyList = propertyList.Remove(propertyList.Length - 1);
    }

    string entityName = typeof(T).Name;
    var baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(baseUrl);
    sb.Append("/api/");
    sb.Append(entityName);
    sb.Append("/");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("?$expand=");
    sb.Append(propertyList);

    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(sb.ToString());
    return response;
}
```

Sorry for my English and if I have to add more informations, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `GetFull()` is a methodname which doesn't tell any caller anything about what the method will do. Please choose always names which are as descriptive as possible.
- this loop

  > ```
  > foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
  > {
  >     if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
  >     {
  >         propertyList += prop.Name + ",";
  >     }
  > }
  >
  > propertyList = propertyList.Remove(propertyList.Length - 1);
  > ```

  could be improved by either using a `StringBuilder` or by using a `ILIst<string>` together with [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This should maybe be extracted to a separate method.
- `if (!entities.Equals("0"))` you are using `entities` without doing any `null` check, so better use `if (!"0".Equals(entities))`. I usually like positive checks more so I would like to suggest to revert this `if..else`.
- by default the newed `StringBuilder` has a capacity of `16` which is doubled if the added value won't fit anymore. So better initialize it with a higher number by using the overloaded constructor which takes the initial size as an argument.
  In addition you can take advantage of the fluent methods of the `StringBuilder` which return the `StringBuilder` itself.

All mentioned points (except for the method name) implemented leads to

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetFull(int id, string entities)
{            
    string propertyList = string.Empty;

    if ("0".Equals(entities))
    {
        propertyList = GetJoinedPropertyList();
    }
    else
    {
        propertyList = entities;
    }

    string entityName = typeof(T).Name;
    var baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);

    sb.Append(baseUrl)
      .Append("/api/")
      .Append(entityName)
      .Append("/")
      .Append(id)
      .Append("?$expand=")
      .Append(propertyList);

    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(sb.ToString());
    return response;
}
private string GetJoinedPropertyList()
{
    IList<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && !prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
        {
            propertyNames.Add(prop.Name);
        }
    }
    return string.Join(",", propertyNames);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for help. It is very helpful for me